# Twitter BootStrap Carousel why added hashtag at end of url

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

i am using Carousel (Slider) when i click on next and prev buttons it add  hashtag #cptbc_105 at end of url i want to remove this , the carousel little jump i don't know why this happen page go to up when i click on next button.

Here is url :  http://goo.gl/m3BlBU

Please help me,
Thanks.

Comment: The only difference to the Bootstrap Example is, you have no `data-ride="carousel"`

Comment: Thanks oliholz i tried but no luck :(

Comment: Your http://goo.gl/m3BlBU link does not work...

Comment: Sorry Link is old goo.gl/m3BlBU no longer available

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that "cptbc_105" is id of your carousel. Page URL changes because you use href="#cptbc_105" on your left and right buttons. Just change "href" attr to "data-target" attr and everyhing will work correctly.

**CHANGE:**

`<a class="right carousel-control" href="#cptbc_105" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>`

**TO:**

`<a class="right carousel-control" data-target="#cptbc_105" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>`